# Javascript loop ISSUE on iteration add blank div if next result not match to current result every 6 count

Tags: javascript, loops

In want to achieve javascript loop as my winning results. The correct example is the below preview.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2BM4.png)

But my result is different I want to know what would be the best ways to achieved the right result using loop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIfGN.png)

I want to achieved every column of 6 records
if the next record is not match to current record it will draw and blank div. If result exceed on the 7th result or so, it will continue create a
L line.

```js
  var results = [{
      "winner": "red",

    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "red",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",
    },
    {
      "winner": "blue",

    }
  ];

var htmlData = '';
var htmlHistory = $('.results');

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  htmlData += '<div class="item ' + results[i].winner + '"></div>';
}

htmlHistory.html(htmlData);
```

```css
.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 192px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-size: 32px 32px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightgrey 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, lightgrey 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: local;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: start;
}

.results .item {
  flex: 1 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 100%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  max-width: 20px;
  max-height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #888888;
}

.item.red {
  border-color: #B31013;
}

.item.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.blank_result {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: when you i is at the position in the grid like 8 9 10 then add the blank_class to this elements and not blue or red

Comment: Hi @Aalexander I want to achieve like letter L result. But I couldn't make it. 

I added counter = 6 and reset every 6th. I want to know how to add blank_class
if the result one first 6 column only 3 are same result.